# I want an ID that will refresh every year

Tags: vb.net

the code is work but when the year changed the id fixed at 1 pls i need help

```
Public con As NewOleDbConnection(
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.ConStr & ";") 

Public Function Max_id()
    Dim mydate = Form6.DateTimePicker3.Value
    Dim myyear = Year(mydate)
    Dim n As Integer

    If myyear = Now.Year Then
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select max(id) FROM table1", con)
        con.Open()
        Try
            n = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Catch
            n = 0
        End Try
    End If

    If myyear > Now.Year Then
        Try
            n = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Catch
            n = 0
        End Try
    End If

    'End If
    con.Close()
    Return n
End Function
```

This code for inserting:

```
Public Sub INSERT_id(datee As Date)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into table1(id,DATE_PIVIé) values(@id,@DATE_PIVIé)", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Max_id() + 1
    cmd.Parameters.Add("DATE_PIVIé", OleDbType.Date).Value = datee
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: If the `ExecuteScalar` method fails and throws an exception, the `Catch` will set `n = 0`, which is returned by `Max_id`, which a `1` is then added to that zero.  So what is the exception being thrown by the `ExecuteScalar`?

Comment: i said i want the id rest every year

Comment: You asked why the id was a 1.  That's probably because the `ExecuteScalar` method call is throwing an exception. You need to determine what the exception is, that will lead you to what the root problem is here.

Comment: the problem the max_id still fixed at 1 when the year change

Comment: In your second If statement cmd is not declared.

Comment: I hope this is not a multi-user database. I guess id is not the Primary Key.

Comment: What about if the user picks a date that is less than the current year in the DataTimePicker? The function will still return zero. A Function should have a return type in the declaration.

Comment: no it is not a multi user database and the , and the user not pick a date manually ,the user just insert but the date change automatically

Comment: how do that the Function should have a return type in the declaration